# iPad apps randomly going gray screen or Home

Tags: ios, ipad

Apps on my iPad 2 are randomly switching to a gray or black screen or dropping me back on the Home screen.

- I am on a slow wifi connection
- All accessibility features are turned off
- Battery is charging normal and is fully power
- Problem happens whether charger is connected or not
- Problem affects all apps

How can I diagnose and/or solve this?

I'm less interested in "just reset / reboot" and more interested to know how it happens and / or if there's a remedy.

Comment: Could you update the question with your iOS version? This can be found in **Settings - General - About**

Comment: You have probably got many apps opened or too many Safari tabs (etc.) and it's lagging too much so it's escaping (timeout).

Answer (score 1):

The iPad 2 is an old device. This lends itself to many crashes.

What you are describing are app crashes. It happens on all devices, but much more frequently on older devices. Since the apps have been updated for never iOS versions, like iOS 10, the iPad is not technically supported by the apps that you're trying to use.

Also, having some extra storage space never hurts, so try deleting some apps to clear up some space.

Beyond deleting apps, the only advice I can give you here is to upgrade to a newer device. Your device is 6 years old, which is a long time for mobile devices.

Comment: the apps are not crashing, they are staying in memory

Comment: Apps stay in the app switcher when they crash.